# Compare and print HTML DOM diffs

Tags: javascript, java, html, dom, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty struggling with this task. I want to run a program that compares 2 HTMLs and prints the diffs in its DOMS. 
Using JAVA
the diffs that interest me are - which elements were deleted, which were added, and which changed location?

I came across Jsoup and thought of combining it with selenium but couldn't really understand how and I struggle with it. I dont mind to use any other lib

My goal is to track the URL layout, so I need to know 
1. How do initially save the URL layout? 
2. How do I compare the "original" saved layout, with the new "production up to date" layout and print the relevant diffs?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried Beyond Compare 4? It seems what you want to do can be done easily with Beyond Compare. You can save the DOM of both HTMLs  and then use BC to compare the differences.

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui that is the result I would like to program. I want to program a method that would give me a result - such an array or a list - of the diffs, w/o using external UI tools

Comment: If your target is to compare with Production UI, I would suggest to use tools like Galen